# React Native android app crash on android 12 after creating a patch for "react-native-nordic-dfu"

Tags: android, react-native, firmware, dfu

I create a new patch using `patch-package` for `react-native-nordic-dfu` and after that my app crash without opening.

When crash the app I'm not getting any error log in metro

Reason to create a patch because `react-native-nordic-dfu` not supporting for Android 12.

This is the patch I added.

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/.DS_Store b/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/.DS_Store
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/android/.DS_Store b/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/android/.DS_Store
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/android/build.gradle b/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/android/build.gradle
index eb225b1..b9c1783 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/android/build.gradle
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-nordic-dfu/android/build.gradle
@@ -1,20 +1,20 @@
 
 buildscript {
     repositories {
-        jcenter()
+        mavenCentral()
         google()
     }
 
     dependencies {
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
     }
 }
 
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
 
-def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 28
-def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '28.0.3'
-def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26
+def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 31
+def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '31.0.0'
+def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 31
 
 android {
     compileSdkVersion project.hasProperty('compileSdkVersion') ? project.compileSdkVersion : DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
@@ -38,6 +38,5 @@ repositories {
 
 dependencies {
     implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
-    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.8.0'
+    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:2.0.1'
 }
-
```

Comment: can you share your patch?

Comment: @KirillNovikov, I edited the question, please take a look.